# What happens when Heroku Papertrail logging reaches 10 MB daily limit?

Tags: heroku, papertrail-app

The free version of Papertrail logging with Heroku has a daily log volume limit of 10 MB:

https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail

What happens when this limit is reached? Does the entire Heroku application fail/crash for the rest of the day? I tried testing this but could not identify what was occurring, so it's not clear to me if the limit even properly triggered for some reason.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it either just stops collecting logs, or continues collecting but old logs roll off the end. I can't find a reference based on a quick search, though. Your app definitely should _not_ crash because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logs will be discarded once you've hit the 10MB, so new logs for that day will not be stored. They'll still be available via Logplex (usually by viewing `heroku logs`) but Papertrail won't have them for you.

Comment: This matches my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Once you hit the daily limit of 10MB the Log processing will be paused.
[See the Papertrail Dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL3hn.png)